# standard error page does not work for forwards in jsf

Tags: jsf, icefaces-1.8

whenever i have a redirect and something goes wrong(eg: NullPointer) then the configured error page is shown. However if i have a forward to certain page then the standard error page is not shown but the current page freezes i.e. the user will not be able to proceed further and there will be no error message too.

when i say forward, it is a navigation rule without `<redirect/>`.
when i say redirect, it is new window opening up.

i am using IBM Websphere.

any pointer would be of great help.
thanks.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10535207/1199132) can be helpful for you.

Comment: Is the exception thrown before or after redirect? If indeed after as guessed, is the initial request a normal or ajax request? If indeed ajax as guessed, are you using JSF 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: @XtremeBiker: thanks. i'll go through that..

Comment: @BalusC: it seems after because the new window opens up..i can see the new URl but the view is of configured error page. initial request is a normal request..through a menu item. i am using jsf1.2/icefaces1.8

Comment: Mmm I was thinking about your IceFaces version. It seems that its tag info was wrong in SO, as it was referring to JSF 2. Already fixed. Following to your question, can you post some more code?

Comment: it started redirecting after i gave .iface as extension instead of .jsp in the <location> element. However, there is one issue to which i don't find any specific answer. there is an ArrayOutOfBoundException thrown in a setter method called during render response phase since i have the value of that property set in my faces-config. Now, when this happens, it is not redirecting. What i could understand till now is it might be converting this exception to FacesException and so its not redirecting. Any views to handle this